# Use values of a list form another class

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am trying to get the available cameras from the device I am dealing with.

For that I am using `final cameras = await availableCameras();` it returns me a list with multiple 'CameraDescriptions'.

I then want the list to be handed to another class that actually uses it to activate the camera. It currently looks like that:

```
class TakePicturePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription cameras;
  TakePicturePage({@required this.cameras});

  @override
  _TakePicturePageState createState() => _TakePicturePageState();
}

class _TakePicturePageState extends State<TakePicturePage> {

  var usedcamera = cameras[0]; //not accepting the first value of 'cameras'

  CameraController _cameraController;    
  Future<void> _initializeCameraControllerFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

      _cameraController =
          CameraController(widget.usedcamera, ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);


    _initializeCameraControllerFuture = _cameraController.initialize();

  }
```

The problem that I am facing is that the first value of 'cameras' can't be assigned to the variable 'usedcamera'. The error even tells me that 'cameras' is not defined. But haven't I already defined it with `TakePicturePage({@required this.cameras});`

Btw the function I get the list 'cameras' from looks like this:

```
void _showCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    print(cameras);

    final result = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => TakePicturePage(cameras: cameras)));
```

So, I am trying to push the data with Navigator.push

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code:

```
_cameraController = CameraController(widget.usedcamera, ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);
```

To access the value of a specific camera, you should do something like

```
_cameraController = CameraController(widget.cameras[0].usedcamera, ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);
```

to access the cameras in the passed list directly.

hope it helps! Please do let me know if this works.

EDIT:

To assign the value to the variable, try var `usedcamera = widget.cameras[0];` The `widget` keyword is used to access the list passed by the `StatefulWidget` inside its `State` class.

Comment: Yeah thanks it does work! But still wondering why I could not assign it to a variable?

Comment: I see what you mean now, try `var usedcamera = widget.cameras[0];`
The `widget` keyword is used to access the list passed by the `StatefulWidget` inside its `State` class

Comment: You are right it stops showing the error, that 'cameras' doesn't exist. But instead it shows an error for 'widget' it says, that only static members can be accessed in initialisers.